# Is there scale by size of all discovered particles?

Tags: elementary-particles, order-of-magnitude, scales

**Atom:**

[image: atom]

**Neutron:**

[image: neutron]

**Elementary particles:**

[image: elementary particles]

Is there scale by size of all discovered particles?

From neutron and proton to electron and to boson?

Compare to each other, like this

[image: solar system]

I have found many similar questions, but there is no graphic:

[Why are particles different sizes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32069/w)

[Comparing scales of atomic level objects to scales of everyday size objects](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14061/)

[How is the size of the particles is determined?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53023/)

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63527/

[Particle Indistinguishability Scale Limit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13455/)

[Ratio of Size of Atom to Size of Nucleus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62044/r)

From the answers I'm achieve that size of particles inconstant like the size of a balloon. But anyway `atom > nucleus > proton > quark`. Is there any imagination like a picture of solar system that I have put here, ***for all discovered particles***.

Or by masses, [E=mc^2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence).

**Edit.**

I have found wonderful movie about: [Horizon: How Small Is the Universe?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2386894/)

Comment: Sizes are not well defined for very small things and there is a whole group of objects currently assumed to have no size: leptons (both charged and uncharged), quarks and all the bosons. Of course, in some candidate next generation theories all these objects have finite size, but there is no experimental indication of what those sizes might be.

Answer (score 4):

Your "sizes" sequence as one goes to smaller and smaller particles stops at the elementary particle table of the [Standard Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model).

[image: elementary particles]

> The Standard Model of elementary particles, with the three generations of matter, gauge bosons in the fourth column and the Higgs boson in the fifth.

Here is a plot that gives sizes of particles which are composed out of atoms and molecules.

[image: sizes of particulate matter]

[Atomic radii](http://www.creative-chemistry.org.uk/alevel/module1/trends5.htm) are of the order of nanometers, different for different elements

Proton and neutron radii are of the order of a fermi (10^-15 meters).

And there we stop.

The elementary particles in the table are point particles as far as the theory which describes with great success  the data hypothesizes. The experimental limits are continually being pushed, [at the moment](http://iopscience.iop.org/1402-4896/1988/T22/016) they are at 10^-^22 meters for the electron, which is the easiest of the elementary particles to experiment with.

The sizes of the non-elementary particles are due to their compositeness, they are made up of other particles. At the present moment, though composite theories for elementary particles  have been and are being proposed, no experimental evidence exists for this. The sequence stops with the elementary particles.

So yes, one could make a sequence, but the stepping is erratic dependent on the many different interactions and groupings that are possible within the particles being organized in size.

Comment: I'm looking for comparisons to each other for particles. Especially, how bigger, e.g. neutron than boson? As Sun bigger than Earth or much more. For every discovered particles.

Comment: @polarbearonthewhitesnow anna answered your question. The elementary particles are not believed to have any size at all. As currently understood they are zero size points. Protons and neutrons (and all hadrons) are about $10^{-15} m$.

Comment: I end my question with alternative - masses, e=mc^2.

Comment: the m in the formula can be  : E_0=m_r, the rest mass identified with the elementary particle , or E=gamma*m_r . We try not to identify m=gamma*m_r with mass identifying a particle since it is a continuous quantity depending on the speed . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_mass .

Answer (score 2):

As already said size of elementary particles is not so simple.

Orderer from high mass to lower (add 125GeV to the Higgs):

[image]

(From Matt Strassler's [blog](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-known-apparently-elementary-particles/))

Anyway, why don't you create an image yourself?

Comment: I'm looking for encyclopedic data

Comment: then look at the particle data group http://pdg.lbl.gov/